# Почему фрагмент исчезает?

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, android-viewpager

Здравствуйте!

Имеется `RecyclerView` в котором есть `CardView` с `ViewPager`. При смене ориентации экрана фрагмент в `ViewPager` тупо пропадает.

Почему так происходит? Спасибо за ответ!

Код адаптера ViewPager:

```
public class MainAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public static Calendar calendar;
public ScheduleFragment fragment;

public MainAdapter(FragmentManager mgr) {
    super(mgr);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return(180);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, position);
    fragment = ScheduleFragment.newInstance(calendar, position);
    return fragment;
}
```

}

Comment: Опубликуйте код адаптера пейджера

Comment: а еще проще проверьте от чего вы наследуете, попробуйте наследоваться от FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: О еее. Спасибо большое, унаследование от FragmentStatePagerAdapter помогло!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста ;)

Comment: оставил ответ для ищущих

Comment: В фрагменте указал setRetainInstance(true)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наследуйте адаптер для `ViewPager` от `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

при смене ориентации, если не сохранить все в `Activity` в методе `onSaveInstanceState` и потом, то что сохранил не вытащил в `onCreate`, все в начальное положение возвращается.

Comment: Фрагменты и так добавляются программно, проблема в том что после поворота устройства содержимое ViewPager полностью исчезает, а не возвращается в начальное состояние.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте фрагмент программно а не layout файле.
Затем как сказал Максим сохраните все в методе onSaveInstanceState , чтоб при смене ориентации экрана данные не пропали

Comment: Фрагменты и так добавляются программно, проблема в том что после поворота устройства содержимое ViewPager полностью исчезает, а не возвращается в начальное состояние.